# gem5 SE mode simulation hangs at the end when using ruby memory model and DerivO3CPU

Tags: gem5

I am trying to run gem5 in SE mode with number of cpus 2, cpu type DerivO3CPU, and ruby memory model using following command, but the simulation does not stop even after results are produced , ie **"Hello world!"** is printed to stdout

```
build/X86_MESI_Three_Level/gem5.opt configs/example/se.py -n 2 --ruby --cpu-type=DerivO3CPU -c 'tests/test-progs/hello/bin/x86/linux/hello;tests/test-progs/hello/bin/x86/linux/hello'
```

I started using ruby memory model after reading from gem5 email archive that classic memory does not work with multicore DerivO3CPU.

Comment: On mailing list: https://www.mail-archive.com/gem5-users@gem5.org/msg17388.html

Comment: @CiroSantilli: thanks for cross linking :) others will be benefited

Comment: @CiroSantilli: Hi, I am running into the same problem, even with just a simple config with no cache and 2 DerivO3CPU init by `system.cpu = [createDerivO3CPU(), createDerivO3CPU()]`. Have you found the solution?

Comment: @Dauto98 I'm afraid not, consider opening a bug report on Jira with extremely detailed reproduction example (gem5 version, example source code, how example was built). If it happens on ARM, I will try to have a look.

Comment: I just upgraded gem5 from 20.0 to 20.1. Now the simulation instead of hanging forever it crashes with the following error `gem5.opt: build/X86/cpu/o3/cpu.cc:823: void FullO3CPU<Impl>::removeThread(ThreadID) [with Impl = O3CPUImpl; ThreadID = short int]: Assertion \`commit.rob->isEmpty(tid)' failed`. Have you seen this before? If not then I will send a mail to the gem5-user mailing list to ask for help.